# IPython inferior process always has preferred locale of 'US-ASCII'

Tags: python, emacs, unicode, ipython

When running IPython under Emacs on OSX as an inferior process I am encountering a strange bug where Unicode strings are not interpreted correctly.

IPython under Emacs:

```
In [10]: print u"\u2713"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-60ae8ccda869> in <module>()
----> 1 print u"\u2713"

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2713' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

IPython at the command line:

```
In [12]: print u"\u2713"
✓
```

I am starting my process through `M-x run-python`. My `os.environ` is different in each process. I am also seeing `locale.getpreferredencoding` is `"UTF-8"` at the console and `"US-ASCII"` in Emacs. However, I don't know how to fix this.

How can I get IPython in Emacs to interpret Unicode strings correctly?

UPDATE: I tried starting the inferior Python process through `python-mode.el` as suggested. The same error occurs.

Comment: Maybe give python-mode.el a try. When loaded, just do M-x ipython RET. Checked your code at openSuse.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I also tried changing to ipython3 but the same issue happens.